# Internet explorer sometimes download pdf as ......xhtml (web page)

Tags: jsf, pdf-generation, response, outputstream

I have followed the recipe for downloading pdf file. Sometimes i can download. But sometimes I am unable to download the actual PDF-file on Internet Explorer.

All I get is an alert box that contains "What you want to do the .....xhtml file?
open or save
"

Anyone see any errors or problems with this code?

Thank you

```
public static void download(byte[] file, String fileName, String mimeType) {

    facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    extCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    resp = (HttpServletResponse) extCtx.getResponse();
    int _BUFSIZE = 32 * 1024;

    int length = 0;
    ServletOutputStream op;
    try {
        op = resp.getOutputStream();
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("ISO 8859-9");
        resp.setContentType(mimeType + ";charset=ISO 8859-9;");
        resp.setContentLength(file.length);
        resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache, must-revalidate");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(file));
        byte[] bbuf = new byte[_BUFSIZE];

        while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
            op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
        }
        in.close();
        op.flush();
        op.close();
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#RESOLVED**

İt is because of the file name includes Turkish characters. And IE doesn't support on the file name that is why returning an empty html file.
I have replaced all TR characters to English Characters.

```
public static void ReplaceTurkishCharsToEnglish(String str){
    str = str.replace("ğ", "g");
    str = str.replace("Ğ", "G");
    str = str.replace("İ", "I");
    str = str.replace("ı", "i");
    str = str.replace("ü", "u");
    str = str.replace("Ü", "U");
    str = str.replace("ö", "o");
    str = str.replace("Ö", "O");
    str = str.replace("ş", "s");
    str = str.replace("Ş", "S");
    str = str.replace("ç", "c");
    str = str.replace("Ç", "C");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your mimeType is "application/pdf", it seems your code is fine.

Try following and test.
In IE;
Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, uncheck "Do not save encrypted files to disk"

PDF is not natively supported in MSIE browsers... You need an installed and enabled PDF file reader ActiveX control to render the PDF file stream.

Comment: Thank you For your comments.  the checkbox "Do not save encrypted files" is already unchecked. I think that the problem is not because of the PDF reader because I can save&open the file sometimes.(when tried to save on other record)